# Clone a remote branch in remote

Tags: git

I already had a remote branch `mainline` on `origin` and now I would like to clone another remote branch (call it `mainline-clone`) from `mainline` on `origin`.

This is what I plan to do:

`git checkout -b mainline-clone origin/mainline`

`git push -u origin mainline-clone`

But I am not sure this is the right way to go since `mainline-clone` is initially set up to track `origin/mainline`, is there any side effect to the `origin/mainline` branch after `git push -u origin mainline-clone`? (I just want to make sure `origin/mainline` would be intact after this `git push`).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a problem, but there's a shorter method:

```
git push origin origin/mainline:refs/heads/mainline-clone
```

will do the job.  (In all cases it's probably wise to run `git fetch` first, before you do any other Git commands here.)

#### Long: what to know

Branch "tracking" information is purely local.  More precisely, each branch in your repository has either no upstream, or one upstream.  If branch *B* has upstream *U*, Git will say that *B* is "tracking" *U*.<sup>1</sup>

The upstream of a branch can be:

- a remote-tracking name, or
- a local branch name

These are meant to be the only two options.

A *remote* like `origin` is just a Git repository: it has its own branch names.  If those branches have upstreams, those upstreams are private to that other Git repository, and you can neither see nor set them from your own Git.  (If the Git repository is on GitHub, those branches do not have upstreams set.)

Each branch name, in any Git repository, simply holds one hash ID.  So you don't need to do this at all:

> ```
> git checkout -b mainline-clone origin/mainline
> ```

That creates your own local name `mainline-clone`, setting its upstream to `origin/mainline`, but you don't need your own local `mainline-clone` yet.  Instead, you can just do:

```
git push origin origin/mainline:refs/heads/mainline-clone
```

The last argument here, `origin/mainline:mainline-clone`, is a *refspec*.  A refspec is, roughly speaking, a pair of names separated by a colon.  The `git fetch` and `git push` commands are the two commands that actually use refspecs.

In any refspec, the name on the left side of the colon is the *source* and the name on the right side of the colon is the *destination*.  The destination of any refspec must be a name—a branch or tag name will usually do, or you can spell out a full *reference name* like `refs/heads/somebranch` or `refs/tags/v2.1` or `refs/remotes/origin/remotetrackingname`.  The source can sometimes be a raw hash ID (when using `git push`), though you don't need that here.

The `git push` command itself means:

- Call up some other Git, by URL or remote-name like `origin`.
- Send that Git commits and/or other objects if/as needed.
- Then, ask that Git to set some of its names—branch names, tag names, whatever—to some hash IDs.

The other Git in this case is `origin`, hence `git push origin ...`.

The commits and other objects needed are: no objects at all; you already have them.

The hash ID you want them to set is the one in your own `origin/mainline` right now.  So that's the *source* part of your refspec.

The name you want them to set is `refs/heads/mainline-clone`: that is, *their* branch named `mainline-clone`.  Using a fully-spelled-out name like this is often unnecessary; you can probably just write:

```
git push origin origin/mainline:mainline-clone
```

But explicitly telling their Git: *this is a branch name* is not harmful, and if your Git doesn't do this, their Git gets to decide whether to treat `mainline-clone` as a branch name, or a tag name, or something else entirely.

Hence you can, explicitly, in your `git push`, say *use my remote-tracking name origin/mainline to set their branch name mainline-clone* by spelling out `origin/mainline:refs/heads/mainline-clone` here.  In fact, it might even be wise, if you're writing a script, to use:

```
git push origin refs/heads/origin/mainline:refs/heads/mainline-clone
```

in case someone accidentally creates a *local* branch (or tag) named `origin/mainline`.  You wouldn't do that yourself, of course. :-)

---

<sup>1</sup>I dislike this use of the word *tracking*, which is already heavily overloaded in Git.  Note that a file is said to be *tracked* if it exists in your work-tree and is in Git's index, and is *untracked* if it exists in your work-tree but not in Git's index; this has nothing to do with branch names.  Meanwhile, names like `origin/master` are *remote-tracking names* or as Git calls them, *remote-tracking branch names*.  This too has nothing to do with branch names, unless you use Git's name for them (which I don't—it's too confusing).